# Multi tenant database connection pool for multiple databases

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, connection-pooling

How I can create multi tenant database connection pool for multiple databases. So basically I want to create  connection pool at Instance level(don't want to create connection pool for every database) and according to request i'll ask connection for particular database and access the database